# Finding basis of range space using non-standard basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I would like to explain my question through an example:

Let $T: F^3 \rightarrow F^3$ be defined by $T(x,y,z) = (x+y+z,x-y+z,x+z)$
We need to find a basis of the range space of this linear transformation.

Now one way is to first use the standard basis $\{ (1,0,0) ,(0,1,0) ,(0,0,1) \} $

$$T(1,0,0) = (1,1,1)$$
$$T(0,1,0) = (1,-1,0)$$
$$T(0,0,1) = (1,1,1)$$

Consider matrix
$$
A= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which is obtained by arranging the images of standard basis row wise

Now we can convert it to echelon form by using elementary row operations which is
$$
A= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0.5 \\
0 & 1 & 0.5 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Therefore a basis of range space is $\{(1,0,0.5) , (0,1,0.5)\}$

Finally my question is : If we started with a non standard basis like $\{(1,0,0) ,(0,1,0) ,(0,1,1)\}$ , then how can we do this process using a non standard basis? All answers are deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do exactly the same. Indeed if $T\colon V\to W$ is a linear map, and $b_1,\dots,b_n$ is any basis of $V$ or even any generating set of $V$, then $T(b_1),\dots,T(b_n)$ is a generating set of the range of $T$. The algorithm you describe via row reduction then reduces a generating set to a basis.